# how to create an alias in VHDL to a port?

Tags: class, port, vhdl, external, alias

I am trying to define an alias in the test-bench to a **PORT** of a sub entity.
My syntax is as follows:

**alias alias_name : < port type > is << signal .tb. < rtl_path > : < port type > >>**

And the error i get is :

**The object specified in class "SIGNAL(driven)" specified for < rtl path > is inconsistent with the class "VHDL INPUT PORT" of the denoted object**

I understand that my problem is in the class that I define after the "<<" but I cant seem to find the proper class that will suit the "VHDL INPUT PORT" instead.

Just to be clear, I don't have the information about signals that are connected to that port so I cant really define the alias to point to a signal. I Need the port aliasing possibility.

Thank you very much.
Itay.

Comment: Just to check, you are compiling for VHDL-2008, right?

Comment: Yes I am. Do you think that its possible?

Comment: Add the smallest possible complete VHDL example that illustrates the problem, and tell us which tool/version you are using.

Comment: I cant give more specific example.

Comment: You can think of the "rtl path" and ".tb.hier.SubHier.Block.PortName" and the the "port type" as "PORT_A" of type std_logic_vector.

Comment: I am using the modelsim 10.2c

Comment: An object alias can't have a subtype indication (IEEE Std 1076-2008, 6.6.2 Object alias, para 1 b)"If the name is an external name, a subtype  indication shall not appear in the alias declaration."). Please provide a code example that will reproduce the error, and the actual and complete error message. Your pseudo code is a not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a bit too abstract.

Comment: This appears to be a [Quartus Prime](http://quartushelp.altera.com/15.1/index.htm#msgs/msgs/evrfx2_vhdl_1737_unconverted.htm) error message, which makes sense for a -2008 external name. "A future version of the Quartus Prime software will provide more extensive Help for this error message."